# How can I smoke a large chicken on an outdoor grill and still keep the skin edible?

Tags: grilling

I smoked a large chicken in an off-set barbecue pit using burning wood only (no charcoal). The meat turned out great, but the skin was saturated with smoke, bitter, and inedible.  I would love to be able to keep the skin edible, any ideas?

Comment: I was using cherry wood

Answer (score 6):

You need to first let the wood burn down to coals before adding your smoking chips and the bird.  The excessive smoke from the burning wood is what made it too bitter.  What type of wood were you burning?